# How to set text-overflow ellipsis correctly for an input element using css and html?

Tags: html, css

i want to set text-overflow ellipsis for an input element. i have the code like below,

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 49px;
}

.input {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 5px 7px 4px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input">
</div>
```

Now the problem with above style is that the ellipsis is shown always when the input is empty like in screenshot [image]

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property on the input itself instead of wrapper

```css
.wrapper {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 49px;
}

.input {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 5px 7px 4px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you're truncating is presumably in the `input` field, but you're applying the `text_overflow: ellipsis` property in the parent `wrapper`. Given that the `input` completely fills the `wrapper`, it's showing the overflow ellipsis because the content (those return characters) overflows the available space.

What you want, though, is for the `input` to have the `text_overflow: ellipsis` property, so you need to move this property into the CSS for that element. Be aware, though, that the input would usually scroll when the user types too much content to view, so you'll want to make sure the resultant behaviour is actually what you want.